# Fastest way to find an entity in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 20k unique labels that each have their own Entity with their own title.

What is the quickest way to get access to an Entity, given its title?

I know this can be done using a predicate, like so

```
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title contains %@", "example title")
```

My issue with this approach is that it involves searching through every single one of the 20k Entities until the right one is found.

Is there a way to do this where all the titles are somehow indexed, and I can instantly get access to any label? Similar to how you can instantly get access to an item in an associative array, with `array['item_name']`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a predicate is how you do it with Core Data.

Before you do anything, is this actually a problem? You don't mention that you've seen any performance issues. Are you having any, or is this still a theoretical problem?

You might improve performance by making sure that the "Indexed" box is checked for this attribute in the Core Data model editor. You might also consider adding a field to your entity that would contain a numeric hash of the title, and fetching based on the hash. You'd still be searching every entity but you'd be doing numeric comparisons instead of strings. You wouldn't be able to do substring searches (as your use of `contains` implies) but you would be doing the same thing as an associative array (which is also called a hash, for exactly this reason).

If none of that works well enough and you're searching strings very frequently, you'll need to investigate a different data model more suited to your needs-- like building a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure for fast searching.

Comment: thanks for the help. I didn't realize that there was an 'indexed' checkbox. you say that integers are much faster to search than strings. Would you be able to explain why this is?

Comment: It's literally almost always this way regardless of platform or language. For a string you need to compare each character in turn. For numbers you do a single comparison.  If your strings average N characters long, numeric comparisons are N times faster on average.